# Proving $e$ exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I saw a cool definition for $e$. Thats cool because they showed how to arrive to it.

Most of the time the definition I see is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ but no one explains how they got it.

The new definition is $e$ is the number such that if you place it in $x$
$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^h - 1}{h} = 1$

The question I have is how can I show that such number exist.

Don't really know how to tackle this and what information can I get from
$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^h - 1}{h} = 1$ to solve this.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is well known that the derivate of $e^x$ is again $e^x$ (In general , $a^x$ has derivate $\ln(a)\cdot a^x$ for $a>0$). This is used in this "new definition". To calculate $e$ , the equality $$e=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}$$ is by the way much more useful , we could consider this to be the "deifnition of $e$" as well.

Comment: it should. i check it right away. and thx